# Compare two dates in years with comma and leap year

Tags: java

There are many entries on the internet how the difference between two dates can be compared. However, I still haven't found the right solution for me.

In short: I'm looking for the equivalent of `dayjs` (javascript library - [dayJs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/difference)) function `diff` with the parameter "years" and a comma. So that I get the output (example): 7.645161290322581 years

```js
const date1 = dayjs('2019-01-25')
date1.diff('2012-06-05', 'year', true) // 6.639424491947131
```

A nice solution would have been `between`. Unfortunately, the following code only gives me the year without a comma.

```java
long diff = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(date1, date2);
```

Sadly, this solution gives me only 6 years and NOT 6.639424491947131.

I've found other solutions, but they don't take leap years into account.

Could someone please help me here.

**//EDIT**

Thanks for the anwers. However days is not an option. I need the years with comma.
Changed 7.49 to 6.639424491947131

Days / 365 is to inaccurate. Sometimes you have a leap year sometimes not.

Comment: Can you just write your own comparator? I am sure you could wrap this functionality inside your own custom function to make it fit your needs.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro convert the dates to LocalDate using a formatter (strng to LocalDate), then getDayOfYear() and divide by 365 or some other maths to get what you want. i dont know of any ready made fn this might help https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

Comment: Why not use a count of days? That is what a decimal fraction of years between dates means: a count of days. A decimal fraction to 15 places creates the illusion of precision that is not actually present when comparing two dates.

Comment: You can get the days like this `long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2);`, and then divide the days by 365.00(or you can calculate it more precisely yourself by taking into account the number of leap years in the range). 

Also shouldn't that function return 6.64.... years, not 7.64...?

Comment: What do you mean by “comma”? I do not see how that applies.

Comment: No, that call to `ChronoUnit.YEARS.between` does not return 7, it returns 6. See [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/25UNHZ).

Comment: We shouldn't need to prove the math with code. A FULL seven years from June, 2012 MUST fall on June of 2019. January 2019 is 5 months short of 7 years. That was me doing an quick "eyeball" test.  Are we that dependent of calculators and software?

Comment: "_Days / 365 is to inaccurate. Sometimes you have a leap year sometimes not_" How do you think a library will accomplish this? It will have to calculate it. There are plenty of online resources to figure out how to accomplish this accounting for leap years. If you need better precision (which I seriously doubt) than dividing elapsed time by 365.25, you can make your function as precise as you want if you spend the time researching how to do the calculation. I am willing to bet the formula is somewhere on the web. We've given you a solid foundation to solve your problem.

Comment: Read this and figure out how to do a super precise calculation accounting for leap years: https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/Numbers/Math/Mathematical_Thinking/calendar_calculations.htm

Comment: @hfontanez 
In the financial sector, everything is always a bit more precise than anywhere else ;-) But that's also a solution for me. If there is no library that calculates this accurately, you just have to program your own function.

Comment: @Paul I have been developing software for a long time.  I am aware of that. But I am willing to bet that you don't know how precise dayjs really is. For all we know, it is doing the calculation exactly like we're showing you. I read the docs and I could not find anything about how the calculation is being made. I think that is the point you are missing here.  IN FACT, since this is an open-source library, you could crack open the library and see how the calculation is done and do the same in Java. Nothing is stopping you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit
.DAYS
.between( 
    LocalDate.parse( "2012-06-05" ) , 
    LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-25" )  
) 
/
365.2425d
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/25UNHZ).

> 6.639424491947131

## Details

Why not use a count of days? That is what a decimal fraction of years between dates means: a count of days. A decimal fraction to 15 places creates the illusion of precision that is not actually present when comparing two dates.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse( "2012-06-05" ) ;
LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-25" ) ;

long daysElapsed = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , end ) ;
```

If you insist on a fraction, divide by whatever fractional count of days per year makes sense to you.

The days per year over a 400 year cycle of the Gregorian calendar is `365.2425`.

```
double DAYS_PER_YEAR = 365.2425d ;
double yearsElapsed = ( daysElapsed / DAYS_PER_YEAR ) ;
```

For accuracy, use `BigDecimal` rather than `double`.

Comment: 365.2425 is the mean. But I need it exactly. There are years with leap years and some without.

Comment: @Paul What does “exact” mean when years have different lengths?  Is the difference between Jan. 1 2019 and June 1 2020 1.5 years exactly?  How would one compute that mathematically?  I’m pretty sure Basil’s approach of dividing by 365.2425 is the best answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll take that with me. I honestly don't know if we can put it like that because in the financial sector it makes a big difference if it's a number 365.0 or 365.2425 and funds are calculated based on that date.

Comment: @Paul `DAYS_PER_YEAR` for this example is arbitrary. You can make that number whatever you want or calculate it to whatever level of precision you need. The important takeaway is that you can (as I suggested) wrap the functionality of standard libraries into your own functions and have said functions do whatever you need them to do. It is impossible for libraries to do EXACTLY what we want. We can use them to get us close. It is up to us to create our own custom code do the rest. This is a good example of that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not saying this is "the answer" but it should be a suggestion for you to base your solution on.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Date date1 = Date.from(Instant.now());
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2021,Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
    Date date2 = cal.getTime();
        
    long diffInMillies = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    long diff = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diffInMillies, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    System.out.println("Difference in days: " + diff);
    BigDecimal yDiff = new BigDecimal(diff/365.25);
    System.out.println("Difference in years: " + yDiff.doubleValue());
}
```

You could take some code like this, and wrap it in a function that manipulates the difference between two dates using standard Java libraries. As you can see in the example below, I used the Java library to calculate the difference of two dates in days, and then I just did a simple calculation to extrapolate the difference in years. I am not sure why this won't be an acceptable compromise.

Using `BigDecimal` instead of `double` gives you more precision as well as an easier way to define significant digits.

Comment: Why are you mixing the terrible legacy date-time classes (`Date`, `Calendar`) with their modern replacements, the *java.time* classes (`Instant`)? If *java.time* is available, there is no need to ever use the legacy classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque for simplicity. I figured the OP would be more familiarized with a "Date" concept. But to your point, you're right. I could've started with this example and expand it to explain the use of the newer and more acceptable "Instant" class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. Its dirty, but work perfectly...

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class AgeCalculator {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int birthYear = 2001;
    int birthMonth = 4;
    int birthDay = 10;
    int birthHour = 0;
    int birthMinute = 0;
    int birthSecond = 0;

    int Year = 2024;
    int Month = 4;
    int Day = 9;
    int Hour = 23;
    int Minute = 59;
    int Second = 59;


    LocalDateTime birthday = LocalDateTime.of(birthYear, birthMonth, birthDay, birthHour, birthMinute, birthSecond, 0);
    LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.of(Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second, 0);

    LocalDateTime tempDateTime = LocalDateTime.from( birthday );

    long full_years = tempDateTime.until( today, ChronoUnit.YEARS );
    tempDateTime = tempDateTime.plusYears( full_years );
    System.out.println( tempDateTime.getDayOfMonth()+"."+tempDateTime.getMonthValue()+"."+tempDateTime.getYear()+ "  "+ tempDateTime.getHour());

    long today_mills = tempDateTime.until( today, ChronoUnit.MILLIS );

    System.out.println( full_years + " years " + today_mills + " mills.");

    int next_birthday_day = birthday.getDayOfMonth();
    int next_birthday_month = birthday.getMonthValue();
    int next_birthday_year = 0;

    if(birthday.getDayOfYear()>=today.getDayOfYear()){
        next_birthday_year = today.getYear();
    }
    else{
        next_birthday_year = today.getYear()+1;
    }

    System.out.println("Next Birthday: "+next_birthday_day+"."+next_birthday_month+"."+next_birthday_year);
    System.out.println("Prev Birthday: "+next_birthday_day+"."+next_birthday_month+"."+(next_birthday_year-1));

    LocalDateTime prev_birthday = LocalDateTime.of(next_birthday_year-1, birthday.getMonth(), birthday.getDayOfMonth(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    LocalDateTime next_birthday = LocalDateTime.of(next_birthday_year, birthday.getMonth(), birthday.getDayOfMonth(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    
    long year_mills = prev_birthday.until( next_birthday, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);

    System.out.println("Millis: "+year_mills);
    System.out.println("Today_Millis: "+today_mills);

    double percentage = (double) (today_mills * 100) / (year_mills*100);
    System.out.println("Full Year: "+(full_years+percentage));
    
}




}
```